# Laravel 4 Rest Api with 2 Parameters

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, rest

I'm trying to make Rest Api using Laravel 4 that uses 2 parameters like this

```
public function jadwal($idKota,$idFilm)
{
    $detil=DB::table('detiltayang')
        ->join('tayang','detiltayang.idTayang','=','tayang.idTayang')
        ->join('bioskop','tayang.idBioskop','=','bioskop.idBioskop')
        ->where('bioskop.idKota','=',$idKota)
        ->where('tayang.idFilm','=',$idFilm)->get();

    return Response::json($detil);
}
```

with route

```
Route::get('api/{idKota}/{idFilm}/jadwal','UrlController@jadwal');
```

but when i check the url in postman it says

```
  <title>Whoops! There was an error.</title>
```

how can you use 2 parameters in rest api laravel? thanks in advance

Comment: api/{idKota}/{idFilm}/jadwal means 2 required parameters (idKota) and (idFilm) in the following order: yoururl.com/api/IDKOTA/IDFILM/jadwal

Comment: Turn the debug level up to get a proper error https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#configuration

Comment: @AntonyThompson Laravel 4 : config/app.php (debug => true)

Comment: @NiekvanderMaaden yes, I did that. this is my url
http://localhost:8080/ecinema/public/api/2/6/jadwal

Comment: Like Antony said, turn on debug mode for a more detailed error message.